# MS Essential Business Server 2008 and activation & installation media question

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ebs, activation, licensing

I want to install a Microsoft Windows Essential Business Server 2008 Premium Edition. Unfortunately I need to start the installation today, but the license and media won't be delivered until end of next week. We have ordered the EBS System Builder version. I have access to the Technet Plus EBS 2008 DVDs. According to the Technet Plus website these DVDs are identical to the retail version DVDs. Could I use these DVDs to install EBS and activate the license with the EBS System Builder version keys when I receive them?

Answer (score 1):

If they are the same versions on the Technet CD's then you can install it and you have a 30 day period to insert the key and activate it. However you cannot install any EBS CAL packs until the servers are activated, but you do get a 30 day grace period for this as well.

Comment: So you think it shouldn't be a problem that the Technet version is the retail edition and the one I've ordered the System Builder version? I should be able to activate the Retail version with the System Builder keys?

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread your original post, thought you were getting retail key. More often than not the Retail keys are different to OEM and VLK keys. Your best bet is prob to ring MS and ask.